# Subsets with small interaction.

Tags: combinatorics

For a set $X$ of cardinality $N$: how can we find a set of subsets of $X$ of cardinality $C$ such that no two subsets have an intersection of more than $n$ elements? What is the largest cardinality of the aforementioned set?

Comment: Which of $n, N, C$, if any, are required to be finite?  It makes a big difference.

Comment: all of them are finite positive integers

Comment: Some motivation? What have you tried?

Comment: I found an upper bound: $\frac{\binom{N}{n+1}}{\binom{C}{n+1}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each subset can be put in correspondence with a binary vector of length $N$, with weight (number of ones) $C$. For example, say $N=5$ and $C=3$, the vector $v=[1, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1]$ (length=5, weight=3), corresponds to selecting the elements 1, 4 and 5.  Clearly, there are  ${5 \choose 3}$ such vectors.

But we have the additional requisite of an intersection of at most $n$ elements for each pair. This is equivalent of having at most $n$ ones in common, or at least $2(C-n)$ different elements. Then, in the binary-codes language, we are after a [constant weight code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-weight_code) (weight $C$ , length $N$)
with minimum Hamming distance of $d = 2(C-n)$. This is a well known and [difficult problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-weight_code#A.28n.2Cd.2Cw.29); there are some [bounds](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.3657.pdf), [tables](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v13i1a2) and [more](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/codingtheory/notes/notes4.pdf).

Comment: I dont understand any of this: what do I need to learn to know this?

Comment: @Khromonkey I amplified a little the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two observations I have made:

We can add all of the subsets of size $n-1$ without any problems. Once we have done that we should add all of size $n$ as possible and never add any larger sets. So the problem is equivalent to finding the maximum number of subsets all of cardinality $n+1$ we can fit.