# Out of all combinations (n,k), largest set such that each combination overlaps with others by d or less.

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

This problem is relevant to determining the number of discriminable combinations of components in a sensory perception task.

Suppose that there are ***N*** components to choose from, and we are only concerned with combinations  of ***k*** of those components, so that there are C(*N*,k) combinations.  I would like to find the size ***s*** of the largest set of those combinations such that each combination in the set shares no more than ***d*** components with each other combination in the set.  For example, given *N*=6, *k*=3, the C(6,3)=20 combinations are:

{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,2,5},{1,2,6},
{1,3,4},{1,3,5},{1,3,6},
{1,4,5},{1,4,6},
{1,5,6},
{2,3,4},{2,3,5},{2,3,6},
{2,4,5},{2,4,6},
{2,5,6},
{3,4,5},{3,4,6},
{3,5,6},
{4,5,6}

And the largest set such that all members have no more than *d*=1 shared component is:
{{1,2,3},{1,4,5},{2,5,6},{3,4,6}}, which has size *s*=4.  If any other combinations were added they would have more than 1 shared component with one of those 4.  There are also other sets of size 4 with this property among those combinations, but none of size 5.

I've also noticed that, in that example, those 4 combinations can be represented as 4 vertices in a hexeract (6-cube), forming a tetrahedron.  I don't know if the best approach to this problem is geometrical or set-theoretical, but either way it is beyond me.

To summarize, I am looking for a function for *s* of the form *s* = f(*N*,k,*d*).

Comment: Hi @RickyG. Welcome! You might like to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Comment: If you represent your sets as vectors of length $N$ with elements $0$ and $1$, where a $1$ in position $j$ indicates that $j$ is a member of the set and a $0$ indicates that it is not, then you are looking at a structure called a [constant-weight code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-weight_code).

Comment: The following [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/267762/3736) may contain useful information.

Comment: Another related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/483762/3736).  I added the tags "coding-theory" and "combinatorial-designs" since these are the fields in which questions like this tend to be studied.  You can also formulate your question as a question about hypergraphs, so I added the "graph-theory" tag as well.

Comment: Thanks, Will, those links were helpful.  It does appear to be a constant-weight-code problem.  They stated the expression as: 
L(n,d,w) <= f(n,d,w) (or alternatively A'(n,d,w) <= f(n,d,w)) where the weight *w* is what I referred to as *k*, and their *d* (the Hamming distance) is 2 times my *d*.  However, my values don't meet the conditions they give to use any of the upper bounds they derive, mostly because the *d* I am interested in (d=2) is too small relative to the *n* I am interested in (n=128).

Comment: Which article do you mean? If we change your $d$ (maximum number of elements two sets may have in common) to $\delta_\text{max},$ and call the number of elements two sets actually have in common $\delta,$ then there are $w-\delta$ elements that the first set has, but the second set hasn't got, and $w-\delta$ elements that the second set has but the first set hasn't got. Hence the Hamming distance between the corresponding codewords is $2(w-\delta).$  Since $\delta\le\delta_\text{max},$ we have $2(w-\delta)\ge2(w-\delta_{max}).$  So their $d$ (minimum distance) is $2(w-\delta_\text{max}).$

Comment: Just to reiterate, I'm wondering how you got that their $d$ is $2\delta_\text{max}$ rather than $2(w-\delta_\text{max}).$  Also, what is your $w$?

Comment: @WillOrrick I was referring to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.3657.pdf).  The application I was considering defines a "replacement" *r* as changing one 0 to 1, and another 1 to 0, hence *d* = 2 *r*.  And I am interested in scenarios such as *n* = 128, *w* = 10, *d* = 2 *r*  = 2.

Comment: I see what you are saying about d vs w-d, though.  In my application w is large compared to the Hamming distance.